# How to insert group footer in crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to insert a Group Footer #1 in crystal report. However, when I have a text object in the section for Group Footer #1 which is after Details, I do not see it in the preview. It could be because this section has diagonal lines in the design view. I am guessing only things in the white background appear in the preview. How do I make the Group Footer appear in the preview?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ita because it was supressed hence it is not visible in preview...

In crystal report wheneve you see diagonal lines in design it means it is either hidden or supressed to end user.

To resolve this

Go to group footer section expert and uncheck supress option..sometimes supress can be a condition in formula in this case you need to got to formula and remove condition